# Android 2.3 emulator orientation changes

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-2.3

I ran into a bit of a problem, which I think is related to the emulator itself. I have put this code right at the top of my `onCreate` method in one of my activities:

```
Log.d(Const.TAG, "onCreate orientation: " + getRequestedOrientation());
```

Everytime I switch orientation in the emulator (via Ctrl+F11 and/or Num 7), it prints `-1` (which corresponds to [`SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED)), and it gets stuck in landscape (doesn't switch back to portrait unless I relaunch the app).

Am I doing something wrong? Is anyone else having this problem? Is it a problem related strictly to the 2.3 emulator or does it appear on devices (Nexus S currently) as well?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but suspected my own code to be responsible for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the emulator, since the Settings app (for example) does the same thing (although the Launcher doesn't, which leads me to believe the Launcher app uses some other mechanism to detect orientation changes).

I'll mark this answer as accepted in a couple days, until then please feel free to shed some light if you have it.

Answer (score 10):

This is a problem with the emulator. See:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189

and on stackoverflow:
[why does the gingerbread emulator orientation get stuck in apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469519/why-does-the-gingerbread-emulator-orientation-gets-stuck-in-apps/4802551)

Unfortunately, this problem isn't addressed with the 10.0 Android SDK (released 2/2011).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with the emulator indeed.

Answer (score 0):

While testing on the 2.3.3 emulator, I am setting  android:screenOrientation="behind" for each activity.