# Why does the android emulator does not rotate back?

Tags: android, macos, orientation, rotation

I'm a Mac user. I just installed the Eclipse and Android SDK. However, I realised that when my emulator rotates from portrait to landscape, the view of the application does not turn back when I press `fn+ctrl+11/12` again but the emulator does.  This does not occur only on my app, it also occurs on the device program such as setting.

Does anyone know the reason behind it ? Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably running into a bug that occurs when the emulator runs certain versions of Android OS. For links, see my answer here: [Android 2.3 emulator orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584376/android-2-3-emulator-orientation-changes/4802683#4802683)

Answer (score 0):

because each rotation is 90 degrees, the first time you tilt it, it will go sideways (90 deg). what you're experiencing when you tilt it again is that the emulator(phone) is now upside-down (180 deg). even normal android devices do not display portrait mode upside-down. tilt it two more times to go back to 0 degrees portrait.