# My android emulator screen is not recognizing the layout-land

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a copy of the layout folder and renamed it as layout-land. In the eclipse; the screen is showing in the landscape mode.

But when I try to rotate the screen in emulator using CTRL+F11; then it rotates the screen instead of showing in the landscape mode.

How do I fix this problem so that the emulator shows the screen in landscape mode? Can someone please help me ??

I have also changed the background color in the layout-land; but the emulator doesn't recognize the color too .. I think it's not recognizing my layout-land at all. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` at all, ive had issues with using that and rotation.

Comment: Do you use emulator with Android 2.3? Because there was definitely a bug with rotating on this version (and probably on some earlier versions). May find the proof later.

Comment: Also, are you sure you haven't fixed the layout orientation for the activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @gjj >> I am using Theme.Light

Comment: @Kzinch Thanks a lot. I was using 2.3 earlier but when I tried it in 4.1 it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add this links as an answer to the question (for anyone who faced this problem as well):

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189

[Android 2.3 emulator orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584376/android-2-3-emulator-orientation-changes)

[why does the gingerbread emulator orientation get stuck in apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469519/why-does-the-gingerbread-emulator-orientation-gets-stuck-in-apps)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Android 2.3, and thus I was unable to rotate the screen. But when I tried in Android 4.1 it works.